# Time and Space complexity for calculating many fish are alive?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was working on a Codility problem:

> You are given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of
>   N integers. Arrays A and B represent N voracious fish in a river,
>   ordered downstream along the flow of the river.
>
> The fish are numbered from 0 to N − 1. If P and Q are two fish and P <
>   Q, then fish P is initially upstream of fish Q. Initially, each fish
>   has a unique position.
>
> Fish number P is represented by A[P] and B[P]. Array A contains the
>   sizes of the fish. All its elements are unique. Array B contains the
>   directions of the fish. It contains only 0s and/or 1s, where:
>
> 0 represents a fish flowing upstream, 1 represents a fish flowing
>   downstream. If two fish move in opposite directions and there are no
>   other (living) fish between them, they will eventually meet each
>   other. Then only one fish can stay alive − the larger fish eats the
>   smaller one. More precisely, we say that two fish P and Q meet each
>   other when P < Q, B[P] = 1 and B[Q] = 0, and there are no living fish
>   between them. After they meet:
>
> If A[P] > A[Q] then P eats Q, and P will still be flowing downstream,
>   If A[Q] > A[P] then Q eats P, and Q will still be flowing upstream. We
>   assume that all the fish are flowing at the same speed. That is, fish
>   moving in the same direction never meet. The goal is to calculate the
>   number of fish that will stay alive.

```
**Complexity:**
```

> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
>   expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

Here is my solution: (100% correct results)

```
public int solution(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int remFish = a.length; 
  int i = 0; 
  for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if(b[i] != 0){
      /*remFish++; }else { */ break; 
    }
  } 
  Stack<Integer> myQ = new Stack<Integer>(); 
  for (int j = i; j < b.length; j++) { 
    if(b[j] == 1)
    {
      myQ.add(j); 
    } 
    while(b[j] == 0 && !myQ.isEmpty()) {
      if(a[j] > a[myQ.peek()]){ 
        myQ.pop(); remFish--; 
      }else{ 
        remFish--; 
      break; 
      }
    } 
  } 
  return remFish;
}
```

Could someone help me understand whether my solution passes the complexity requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Idea was good.
I tried to make it more understandable.

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {

        int numFishes = A.length;

        // no fishes
        if(numFishes == 0)
            return 0;

        // Deque stores the fishes swimming downstreams (B[i]==1) 
        Deque<Integer> downstreams = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){

            //Fish is going downstreams
            if(B[i] == 1){
                // push the fish into the Deque
                downstreams.push(A[i]); 
            }//Fish is going upstreams
            else{
                while( !downstreams.isEmpty() ){ 
                    // Downstream-fish is bigger 
                    if( downstreams.peek() > A[i] ){
                        //Upstream-fish gets eaten
                        numFishes--;
                        break;    
                    }// Downstream-fish is smaller
                    else if(downstreams.peek() < A[i]){
                        //Downstream-fish gets eaten
                        numFishes--;
                        downstreams.pop();
                    }
                }
            }  
        }    

        return numFishes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow this code with the strange data structures and lack of variable names, but I *think* I have the needed understanding ...

**Space complexity**:
The only dimensioned space you have is `myQ`, which is bounded by the total quantity of fish.  Thus, this is **O(n)**.

**Time Complexity**:
Given your strange logic, this was harder to follow.  The paired decrements of `remFish` and the abuse of `while -- break` confused me for a couple of minutes.  However, the simpler analysis is ...

The `while -- break` turns that loop into a simple `if` statement, since you *always* break the loop on first iteration.  Therefore, your only true iteration is the `for` loop, bounded by the quantity of fish.  Thus, this is also **O(n)**.

Among other properties, note that you decrement `numFish` on each iteration, and it never drops as far as 0.

---

Why do you gauge one iteration on a.length and another on b.length?  Those must be the same, the starting quantity of fish.

Comment: This is wrong, he does not break the while loop on the first iteration, and while loop is not turned into a simple if statement.

Comment: Right; I see my error now, stemming from the original formatting.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

`N` fish get a series of `O(1)` checks.  That's `O(n)`.

The `O(n)` fish swimming downstream get added to `myQ` which is also `O(1)` each for another `O(n)` term.

Every iteration of the inner loop kills a fish in `O(1)` time.  At most `O(n)` fish die so that is also `O(n)`.

Adding it all up, the total is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got 100/100 with this code. I've seen other solutions more concise. But this one is pretty readable.

```
ArrayDeque<Integer> downstreams = new ArrayDeque<>();
    int alive = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        int currFish = A[i] * (B[i] == 1 ? -1 : 1);
        if (currFish < 0) {
            downstreams.push(currFish);
            alive++;
        } else {
            Iterator it = downstreams.iterator();
            boolean eaten = false;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int down = (int) it.next();
                if (Math.abs(currFish) > Math.abs(down)) {
                    it.remove();
                    alive--;
                    eaten = false;
                } else {
                    eaten = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!eaten) {
                alive++;
            }
        }
    }
    return alive;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is python3 try with time complexity O(N)

```
def fish_eater(fish_size, direction):
    stack = []
    fish_alive = len(fish_size)
    if not len(fish_size):
        return 0
    for i in range(len(fish_size)):
        if direction[i] == 1:
            stack.append(fish_size[i])
        else:
            while len(stack):
                if stack[-1] > fish_size[i]:
                    fish_alive -= 1
                    break
                if stack[-1] < fish_size[i]:
                    fish_alive -= 1
                    stack.pop()
    return fish_alive
```

Useful resource about time complexity and big O notation
[understanding-time-complexity-with-python](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-time-complexity-with-python-examples-2bda6e8158a7)